# Нижняя граница поддерживаемой версии iOS для современного приложения

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Прошу поделиться опытом тем, кто сейчас разрабатывает коммерческие приложения под iOS. Я пишу несложное приложение которое почти не использует блоки, GCD и прочее что мешало бы запускать его на более ранних версиях в связи с чем встал вопрос целесообразности поддержки старых верисй iOS. Какую нижнюю планку поддержки версии имеет смысл реализовывать в приложении сейчас? Есть ли у заказчиков сейчас требования делать под 4.3 или даже более старые версии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно посмотреть статистику и сделать соответсвующие выводы:  [iOS Version Stats](http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/).

Comment: Эта статистика делается как я понял по одному приложению. Можно ли ее считать репрезентативной?

Comment: Конечно данная статистика дает лишь приблизительную оценку и на нее всецело полагаться никак нельзя. Но я добавил бы следующее, что всегда будет определенный процент людей, которые остаются со старой версией iOS. Судя по всему это люди, которые довольно пассивны в качестве покупателей и на них вряд ли можно возлагать большие надежды в плане маркетинга и рассматривать их в качестве потенциальных покупателей. Но возможно, что поддержка одного двух релизов iOS назад можно себе позволить без особых усилий.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий!